# How to display response from Cordova-Calllog-Plugin for Android by using Visual Studio Community

Tags: cordova

I am a new Cordova-Plugins learner and trying to get Phone Call History and display in Html table. I created a TypeScript project in Visual Studio and added the Cordova-Calllog-Plugin from git. I modified the default index.html page given below but its not working. Please help me to make it working. I have spent many hours on it but failed. here is my code

```
    <body>
    <div>
        <h1>Call History</h1>
        <div id="deviceready">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p><hr />
            <button onclick="loadLogs();">Display History</button>
            <div id="id01"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/appBundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        function loadLogs() {
            var out = "<table style='border:solid;'><thead><tr><td>Number</td><td>Date</td><td>Type</td></tr></thead>";
            document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
            window.plugins.calllog.list(1, function (response)
            {
               alert("Going to use the response and add rows to the Html Tble table ");
               alert(response); // its giving the response [Object Object]
               // checked the length of response
               var length = 0;
               for (var i in response) {if (isFinite(i) && i > length) length = i; }
               alert("response length:" + length); // its giving response length:0

                // Assumed that the response is a JSON Object so tried to parse it
                var arr = JSON.parse(response);
                alert("Array Lenth:" + arr.length); // Its not showing anything
                   var i;
                   for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                       alert("Loop Started:" + i); // to check if entering in the loop but its not reaching here
                       out += "<tr><td>" + arr[i].number + "</td><td>" + arr[i].date + "</td><td>" + arr[i].type + "</td></tr>";
                       alert(out); // just to check result of each row
                   }
                   out += "</table>";
                   document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
                   alert(out);
                   alert("Successfull");
            }, function (error)
            {
                // Damn got an error. useful print it
            });
            alert("Finished")
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Its working now. A BIG Thanks to phonelog who helped me on this. The complete working code is here which was revised as per suggestion given in Answer#1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Call History</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/appBundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function onLoad() { document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); }
        function onDeviceReady() { alert("Hello Stage#1 DeviceReadyEvent Fired and Device is Ready") }
        function loadLogs() {
            var out = "<table><thead><tr><td>Number</td><td>Date</td><td>Type</td></tr></thead>";
            document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
            window.plugins.calllog.list(2, function (response)
            {
                var rows = response.rows;                
                for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
                    { out += "<tr><td>" + rows[i].number + "</td><td>" + rows[i].date + "</td><td>" + rows[i].type + "</td></tr>"; }
                document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out + "</table>";
            }, function (error) {
                alert("There is something wrong")
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <h1>Call History</h1>
    <div id="deviceready">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device ... </p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>        
    </div>   
    <button onclick="loadLogs();">Click here to get Call History</button>
    <div id="id01"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Calllog.js

```
function CallLog() {
}

CallLog.prototype.list = function (period, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "CallLog", "list", [period]);
};

CallLog.prototype.contact = function (phoneNumber, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "CallLog", "contact", [phoneNumber]);
};

CallLog.prototype.show = function (phoneNumber, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "CallLog", "show", [phoneNumber]);
};

CallLog.prototype.delete = function (id, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "CallLog", "delete", [id]);
};

CallLog.prototype.insert = function (args, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "CallLog", "insert", args);
};

CallLog.install = function () {
  if (!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
  }

  window.plugins.calllog = new CallLog();
  return window.plugins.calllog;
};

cordova.addConstructor(CallLog.install);
```

Here is the CallLogPlugin.java

```
package com.ubookr.plugins;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult.Status;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class CallLogPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    private static final String ACTION_LIST = "list";
    private static final String ACTION_CONTACT = "contact";
    private static final String ACTION_SHOW = "show";
    private static final String ACTION_DELETE = "delete";
    private static final String ACTION_INSERT = "insert";
    private static final String TAG = "CallLogPlugin";
    // Permission request stuff.
    private static final int READ_CALL_LOG_REQ_CODE = 0;
    private static final String PERMISSION_DENIED_ERROR =
        "User refused to give permissions for reading call log";
    // Exec arguments.
    private CallbackContext callbackContext;
    private JSONArray args;
    private String action;

    public static final String READ_CALL_LOG =
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG;

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
            final CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        Log.d(TAG, "execute called");

        this.action = action;
        this.args = args;
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;

        if (cordova.hasPermission(READ_CALL_LOG)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission available");
            executeHelper();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No permissions, will request");
            cordova.requestPermission(this, READ_CALL_LOG_REQ_CODE,
                    READ_CALL_LOG);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void executeHelper() {
        Log.d(TAG, "executeHelper with action " + action);
        if (ACTION_CONTACT.equals(action)) {
            contact();
        } else if (ACTION_SHOW.equals(action)) {
            show();
        } else if (ACTION_LIST.equals(action)) {
            list();
        } else if (ACTION_DELETE.equals(action)) {
            delete();
        } else if (ACTION_INSERT.equals(action)) {
            insert();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Invalid action: " + action + " passed");
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(
                    new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION));
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionResult(
            int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            int[] grantResults) throws JSONException {
        for (int r : grantResults) {
            if (r == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission denied");
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(
                        new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                            PERMISSION_DENIED_ERROR));
                return;
            }
        }
        executeHelper();
            }

    private void show() {
        //        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PluginResult result;
                try {
                    String phoneNumber = args.getString(0);
                    viewContact(phoneNumber);
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
                }
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
            }
        });
        }

    private void contact() {
        // TODO: this code path needs to ask user for permission, currently
        // it does not.
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PluginResult result;
                try {
                    final String phoneNumber = args.getString(0);
                    String contactInfo = getContactNameFromNumber(phoneNumber);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Returning " + contactInfo);
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, contactInfo);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
                }
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
            }
        });
    }

    private void list() {
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PluginResult result;
                try {
                    String limiter = null;
                    if (!args.isNull(0)) {
                        // make number positive in case caller give negative days
                        int days = Math.abs(Integer.valueOf(args.getString(0)));
                        Log.d(TAG, "Days is: " + days);
                        //turn this into a date
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTime(new Date());
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -days);
                        Date limitDate = calendar.getTime();
                        limiter = String.valueOf(limitDate.getTime());
                    }
                    // Do required search
                    JSONObject callLog = getCallLog(limiter);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Returning " + callLog.toString());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, callLog);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got NumberFormatException " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, "Non integer passed to list");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
                }
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
            }
        });
    }

    private void viewContact(String phoneNumber) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT,
                Uri.parse(String.format("tel: %s", phoneNumber)));
        cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);
    }

    private void delete() {
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PluginResult result;
                try {

                    int res = CallLogPlugin.this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, "_ID = " + args.getString(0), null);
                    if (res == 1) {
                        result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, res);

                    } else {
                        result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, res);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
                }
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
            }
        });
    }

    private void insert() {
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                PluginResult result;
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                Uri uri;

                try {
                    values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, args.getString(0));
                    values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION, args.getInt(1));
                    values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE);
                    values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
                    values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "");
                    values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
                    values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");

                    uri = CallLogPlugin.this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);

                    result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, uri.toString());

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got Exception " + e.getMessage());
                    result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
                }

                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
            }
        });
    }

    private JSONObject getCallLog(String limiter) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject callLog = new JSONObject();

        String[] strFields = {
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL };

        try {
            Cursor callLogCursor = this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                    strFields,
                    limiter == null ? null : android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?",
                    limiter == null ? null : new String[] {limiter},
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

            int callCount = callLogCursor.getCount();

            if (callCount > 0) {
                JSONObject callLogItem = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray callLogItems = new JSONArray();

                callLogCursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    callLogItem.put("date", callLogCursor.getLong(0));
                    callLogItem.put("number", callLogCursor.getString(1));
                    callLogItem.put("type", callLogCursor.getInt(2));
                    callLogItem.put("duration", callLogCursor.getLong(3));
                    callLogItem.put("new", callLogCursor.getInt(4));
                    callLogItem.put("cachedName", callLogCursor.getString(5));
                    callLogItem.put("cachedNumberType", callLogCursor.getInt(6));
                    callLogItem.put("cachedNumberLabel", callLogCursor.getInt(7));
                    //callLogItem.put("name", getContactNameFromNumber(callLogCursor.getString(1))); //grab name too
                    callLogItems.put(callLogItem);
                    callLogItem = new JSONObject();
                } while (callLogCursor.moveToNext());
                callLog.put("rows", callLogItems);
            }

            callLogCursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("CallLog_Plugin", " ERROR : SQL to get cursor: ERROR " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return callLog;
    }

    private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
        // define the columns I want the query to return
        String[] projection = new String[] {
            PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

        // query time
        Cursor c = cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

        // if the query returns 1 or more results
        // return the first result
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            c.deactivate();
            return name;
        }

        // return the original number if no match was found
        return number;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier, than you thought ;) Take a look at following code:

```
function loadLogs() {
        var out = "<table style='border:solid;'><thead><tr><td>Number</td><td>Date</td><td>Type</td></tr></thead>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
        window.plugins.calllog.list(7, function (response) {

            var rows = response.rows;
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                out += "<tr><td>" + rows[i].number + "</td><td>" + rows[i].date + "</td><td>" + rows[i].type + "</td></tr>";
            }
            out += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;

        }, function (error) {
            // Damn got an error. useful print it
        });
    }
```

Make sure that the code is run, after the deviceready event fired. Otherwise you'll run into an error.

Comment: Hi Buddy, It was my first post and you was the first respondent. As per your advice I added deviceready event and changed the code. It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. You saved my project otherwise I was about to drop it. I added the revised working code in the post, in case anybody else need it.